# Wordpress - How to deal with two Wordpress website for the same domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm facing a strange problem with Wordpress.

Few years ago, I installed a Wordpress on my hosting plan. It works fine.
Today I would like to add a second one Wordpress dedicated to photography.

/www/ -> original Wordpress
/www/photographies/ -> Wordpress dedicated to photography.

Moreover, my domain name point to the root directory of my server so :

my-domain.com -> /www 
photographies.my-domain.com -> /www/photographies/

I configured the second Wordpress (settings ribbon) to specify the URL (photographies.my-domain.com). I can browse the second website (homepage), however I get a 500 error when I try to access a content with rewrited URL.

So photographies.my-domain.com works well, but photogaphies.my-domain.com/2014/02/my-post doesn't work.

Any idea to solve that ? I can't change server settings with my hosting plan.
Should I buy another hosting plan ?

Comment: What you need is called "multi-bloging", read more here http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs

Comment: Read this : http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 0):

Put them in separate directories :
my-domain.com -> /www/main 
photographies.my-domain.com -> /www/photographies/

Your issue is about the url_rewrite in file the .htaccess, that exists on both websites.